# What's the best way to check for the presence of a hash?

Tags: javascript, html, hash

Right now I'm using

> ```
> if(window.location.hash != '')
> ```

Is this foolproof? Or, is there a way to return a Boolean value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will return empty string if the hash symbol is present in the URL but it doesn't have anything on it's right side. If there's a value it will return the value with the hash symbol as first character. This might be a bit confusing in certain situations.

Part from that I'd say it's a pretty solid way of using it.